# Unity fading alpha of TMPro text causes noticeable frame rate drop

Tags: unity, c#, text-mesh-pro

I am using this code to change the transparency of my TMPro TMPUGUI text when changing a page (from a book).

```csharp
// called in start, and on button press
public void ShowPage(int index, bool ignoreFade=false)
{
    if (changeWithFade && !ignoreFade)
    {
        if (isFading) 
        {
            Debug.Log("LogViewBehaviour: Still fading, action cancelled!");
            return;
        }
        isFading = true;
        StartCoroutine(DoShowPage(index));
    }
    else
    {
        textAnimator.SetText("", false);
        textAnimator.SetText(logTextRenderer.GetFormattedPageText(LogStore.GetPageByIndex(index)), false);
        StartCoroutine(ScrollToBottom());
        currentPage = index;
   }
}

IEnumerator DoShowPage(int index)
{
    yield return FadeText(textMesh, 1, 0, fadeDuration);
    textAnimator.SetText(logTextRenderer.GetFormattedPageText(LogStore.GetPageByIndex(index)), false);
    currentPage = index;
    yield return ScrollToBottom(); 
    yield return FadeText(textMesh, 0, 1, fadeDuration);
    isFading = false;
}

IEnumerator FadeText(TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI sourceToFade, float startAlpha, float endAlpha, float duration)
{
    float startTime = Time.unscaledTime;

    while (true)
    {
        float elapsed = Time.unscaledTime - startTime;
        float t = elapsed / duration;

        sourceToFade.alpha = Mathf.Clamp01(Mathf.Lerp(startAlpha, endAlpha, t));

        if (sourceToFade.alpha == endAlpha)
        {
            break;
        }

        yield return null;
    }//end while
}

IEnumerator ScrollToBottom()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    scrollRect.verticalNormalizedPosition = 0f;
}
```

Every time this is executed, my game noticeably lags, the frame rate drops significantly until the fade is finished.
The text is several paragraphs long, mostly hidden inside a scroll rect.

I tried a Canvas group on the text gameobject, but it disabled interactions.

What's the best way to approach this?